# TypeError: $(...).unload is not a function - JQuery 3.1.0

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to execute a function before redirecting to other page, but when the original page loads I get the error that I wrote in the title:

```
TypeError: $(...).unload is not a function
```

I've tried this:

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
  return "Bye now!";
});
```

And this:

```
$(window).unload(function(){
  cambiar_ruta();
  alert(ruta);
});
```

But nothing is working,I don't even get a Leaving page warning.

With next code I don't get an error, but the function is never triggered and the alert never shown:

```
var ruta;
$(window).bind('onbeforeunload', function(e){
  alert('Bye.');
  cambiar_ruta();
  alert(ruta);
});
```

I'm using jquery-3.1.0.min

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try to change like below, because you are using jquery-3

```
$(window).on("unload", function() {
    alert("call");
    console.log("this will be triggered");
});
```

Comment: With that I don't get an error, but doesn't shows the alert and also nothing in the console. I'm redirecting with this `$(location).attr('href', '/report_excel?codigo='+ruta);` It redirects to a page that downloads an excel file when a button is clicked. I was trying to change the `ruta` value before sending it, but now I'm doing it when some selects and text input values changes. Your solution fixed the error, but don't fixed my problem, but I think is a good solution. And something funny happened, the console message shows when I enter to the page, not when I'm leaving.

Answer (score 11):

The correct answer would be this:

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() { 
    // your codes
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, as of Chrome on a PC in Apr 2020, this is not triggered

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Versione 105.0.5195.127 (Build ufficiale) (a 64 bit)
jQuery v3.6.0

```
var state=null;
function cleanup(i) {
  //cleanup
  state=i;
}
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() {
  /*
    cases
    #1 handler terminate without return instruction
    => execute function exit without prompt

    #2 handler terminate  with return with no arguments
    => execute function exit without prompt

    #3 handler terminate with return anyvalue
    =>execute function and exit with prompt

    notes
    #if you have an alert or prompt in handler or in the called function will be blocked  with an error
    #text of buttons prompt changes based on user action
    refresh  page   =>refresh,cancel
    any link outside page =>       exit,cancel
    close tab  => exit,cancel
  */
  /*
    var anyvalue=true;
    var anyvalue=false;
    var anyvalue=parseInt("-1");
    var anyvalue=parseInt("0");
    var anyvalue=parseInt("1");
    var anyvalue=null;
  */
  cleanup(1);
  //case 1
  //return;//case 2
  //return anyvalue;//case 3 uncomment any anyvalue
});
```