# Uncaught TypeError: b(...).unload is not a function in jquery-3.2.1

Tags: jquery

Getting the above error after upgrading jquery from 1.6.2 to 3.2.1. But not able to find the unload function anywhere in the library to make changes

Comment: Please update your question and add the actual error to the body with proper formatting. Also, provide more information about your project.

Comment: Try and take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030910/typeerror-unload-is-not-a-function-jquery-3-1-0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: $(...).unload is not a function - JQuery 3.1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030910/typeerror-unload-is-not-a-function-jquery-3-1-0)

Comment: @Soviut the accepted answer on this question you link to is a bad practice.

Comment: use this <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
         console.log("beforeUnload event!");
     });
</script>

Answer (score 3):

This function was first deprecated in 1.8 and then removed.

You could in theory replace it with

```
.on("unload", function(){
```

which it was a shortcut for.

But it was removed for a good reason: listening for this event is usually a bad practice. The truth is there's no real cross-browser and reliable solution to handle page termination. The real solution is to avoid relying on this event.  You must design your application so that you don't have anything to do on page closing.

Comment: Maybe in another imported 3rd lib script?